# how can i use multer to upload a video and force the format to be mp4

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, video, multer

I have implemented imaged upload using multer and I am receiving the images back to my front end app built with angular. Now I want to do the same with video, upload the video such that I accept all video formats but store on mp4 or other acceptable formats. I have searched everywhere but cant not seem to find out if multer can process video. Here is my implementation so far.

```
const router = require('express-promise-router')();
const VideosController = require('./video.controller');
const { validateParam, validateBody, schemas } = require('../_middleware/routehelpers');
const db = require('../_helpers/db');
const Video = require('./video.model');
const passport = require('passport');
const passportConfig = require('../passport');
const passportLogin = passport.authenticate('local', {session: false});
const passportJwt = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false });

const multer = require('multer');
const videoFilter = require('./videoFilter');
```

// Save file to server storage

```
 var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: (req, file, cb) => {
          cb(null, './public/videos');
        },
        filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    
           
          
          var filetype = '';
          if (file.mimetype === 'video/gif') {
            filetype = 'gif';
          }
          if (file.mimetype === 'video/mp4') {
            filetype = 'mp4';
          }
          if (file.mimetype === 'video/ogg') {
            filetype = 'ogg';
          }
          if (file.mimetype === 'video/wmv') {
            filetype = 'wmv';
          }
          if (file.mimetype === 'video/x-flv') {
            //filetype = mime.getExtension('video/flv');
            filetype = 'flv';
          }
          if (file.mimetype === 'video/avi') {
            filetype = 'avi';
          }
          if (file.mimetype === 'video/webm') {
            filetype = 'webm';
          }
          if (file.mimetype === 'video/mkv') {
            filetype = 'mkv';
          }
          if (file.mimetype === 'video/avchd') {
            filetype = 'avchd';
          }
          if (file.mimetype === 'video/mov') {
            filetype = 'mov';
          }
          cb(null, 'video-' + Date.now() + '.' + filetype);
        }
      
      });
      
      var upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: videoFilter.videoFilter });
```

// my routes

```
router.route('/')
.post(passportJwt,upload.single('file'),VideosController.addNewVideo);

//my controller

 addNewVideo: async (req, res, next) => {       
        // check file for Validation Error
     if (req.fileValidationError) {
         return res.send(req.fileValidationError);
     }
     else if (!req.file) {
         return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Upload fail'});
     } else {
         // if no Validation Error
        // hbjs.spawn({ input: 'something.avi', output: 'something.m4v' })
       // console.log('req.file.filename',req.file.mimetype )
         req.body.videoUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/videos/' + req.file.filename;
 
         //get the body
         const newVideo = req.body;
         //get the user
         const userId = req.user._id;
         //assign new video to the user
         newVideo.userId = userId;
         // create the new video
         const video = await new Video(newVideo);
         // save the new Video
         await video.save();
         //get the user from db
         const user = await db.User.findById(userId);
         // save the new video to user collections
         await user.user_videos.push(video);
         await user.save();
 
         //respond to client
 
         res.status(200).json(video);
        
     }
 },
```

//////
I tested with .flv, the file is saved on the public/videos but I wish to convert all files to popular format only

Comment: Is this problem solved ? if solved, please let me know the solution. I am also facing the same problem and didn't found any solution anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You would need to send the saved video file on the node server to an encoder to be encoded to another file.

ffmpeg supports all video types and is very flexible.

I do believe theres a node package but the original command line is preferred.